# Diferenças entre ouvido e orelha

Tags: significado, português-brasileiro

Quais são as diferençes entre *ouvido* e *orelha*?

Procurando no internet, parece que os dois significam **ear** em inglês, mas **ouvido** é mais relativo à Medicina e **orelha** é mais comum e relativo à parte exterior de **ear**! Está certo?

Também, posso usar os dois alternadamente em conversação como:

> Eu tenho dois furos de brinco em cada orelha/ouvido!

?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Existem três termos básicos: orelha, ouvido, pavilhão auricular (o último utilizado apenas em meio biomédico).

### Orelha:

Designa o aparelho auditivo como um todo, todo o órgão e sua estrutura. [1](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=Dicion%C3%A1rio#dobs=orelha)

> orelha
>
> ê/
>
> substantivo feminino
>
> 1. anat.hum órgão da audição, que possui três partes principais (externa, média e interna). Anteriormente denominado ouvido.

É usado popularmente para referenciar o pavilhão auricular, a parte da orelha que se pode tocar — inclusive o lóbulo.

### Ouvido:

[Designa a parte interna do órgão orelha, o que abrange o martelo (osso), estribo (osso), cóclea, membrana tectorial, tímpano, etc. Tudo o que não se pode normalmente tocar.](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orelha#Ouvido)

Também significa, figurativamente, o sentido da audição, como em: "*Ouvido apurado*", que conota boa audição.

### Pavilhão auditivo/auricular:

[Isto.](https://www.google.com.br/search?biw=1366&bih=637&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=QjIYW9GhCMmBwgT-mJvAAg&q=pavilh%C3%A3o%20auditivo&oq=pavilh%C3%A3o%20a&gs_l=img.1.0.0l10.383.586.0.1973.2.2.0.0.0.0.223.414.0j1j1.2.0....0...1c.1.64.img..0.2.413...0i67k1.0.ZB574q9tnQw#imgrc=VjRN5Lmw4QNCYM:)

Comment: ! Então eles não podem ser substituído?

Comment: @Majid No Brasil, se diz 'furo na orelha', 'furo no ouvido' soa **muito** estranho. Aguardo um português para esclarecer a expressão em pt-pt.

Comment: @Majid Popularmente, entretanto, o uso de ouvido e orelha depende do contexto, ouvido geralmente se usa em contexto de audição, como um som muito alto que machuca o ouvido; orelha geralmente se usa em contexto físico, como sentir a orelha (pavilhão auricular) arder ou doer.

Comment: @Majid, concordo com o William. Se não me engano, foi há alguns anos que "orelha" passou a ser usada para o órgão de audição todo - uma mudança que seria parte de uma atualização da nomenclatura médica, para alinhá-la à nomenclatura internacional. Nessa mesma atualização, se não me falha a memória, aquele ossinho na frente do joelho teria tido seu nome mudado de "rótula" para "patela".

Comment: obrigado a todos!

Comment: `Utilizado em Portugal para se referir ao órgão em si (orelha).` Podes dar um exemplo público desse uso? De um jornal, uma entrevista, qualquer coisa? Não reconheço isto. Para mim, enquanto português, ouvido é só a parte interna da orelha. Por exemplo: se alguém me dissesse que tinha um furo no ouvido, perguntava-lhe se era surdo desse lado.

Comment: @ANeves, concordo: "orelha furada" tem um furo para pôr um brinco; "ouvido furado" para mim significaria tímpano furado ou outro furo interno. "Orelha" é sempre a parte externa (orelhas pequenas/grandes, puxou-lhe a orelha, beijou-lhe a orelha); "ouvido" é interno (dor de ouvido, cera nos ouvidos) ou até mesmo a capacidade de audição (ouvido apurado).

Comment: @ANeves Encontrei um verbete no wiktionary, porém nenhum exemplo. Retirei a sentença.

Comment: Nunca ouvi falar em dor de  orelha. Dor de ouvido e orelhas furadas, que nem papo.

Comment: (@William Em pt-PT, sentença é uma decisão de tribunal. Só "frase" poderia ser usado aí.)